Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information). how to fix the issue in the deployment
I'm experiencing an issue with dynamic routing in my Next.js application when deployed on cPanel. This issue does not occur during local development. The error message is:
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information). The console log shows the following error:
GET https://prosale.cloud/_next/static/chunks/app/(hydrogen)/employee/%5Bid%5D/edit/page-7ae4d87d174c4f0f.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) ChunkLoadError at __webpack_require__.f.j (webpack-2a0249f03633b4d2.js:1:13047) ...
The file page-6d6c06c2fb38fc4a.js is present in the correct directory on the server. I've ensured that all files are correctly built and uploaded. Could someone guide me on how to resolve this issue with the dynamic route?
Thank you!
I have tried deleting the cache and other related setting but not able to solve this.
In the local build its running good.
